# Back button on Title bar not working for pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android

I added a back button on the titlebar for some of my activities in my app.The back button works fine for Lollipop devices but when I tested my app on Icecream Sandwich device, the back button does not work.Here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);   //Adding back button
    List<ItemObjectArticle> rowListItem = getAllArticleItemList();
    lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(ArticleActivity.this);
    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
    ArticleAdapter rcAdapter = new ArticleAdapter(ArticleActivity.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }else if(id==R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);  //handling click
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And in the Android Manifest file, i added:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ArticleView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_article_view"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.kheti.ArticleActivity">   //this
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.android.kheti.ARTICLEVIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What code do i need to change to make it work on all Android devices?

Comment: Just a guess: In method `onOptionsItemSelected()`, try using `android.R.id.home`.

Comment: @qbix , Thanks, but it worked in both cases by adding meta-data element in `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Using `android.R.id.home` and `R.id.home` is equivalent in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> Beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), you can declare the logical
>   parent of each activity by specifying the android:parentActivityName
>   attribute in the  element.
>
> If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the Support
>   Library with your app and add a  element inside the
>   . Then specify the parent activity as the value for
>   android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY, matching the
>   android:parentActivityName attribute.

So you need to add  the meta-data for make it work in all devices.
Add the support library and try with this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ArticleView"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_article_view"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.android.kheti.ArticleActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.android.kheti.ArticleActivity" />
 </activity>
```